# Will an Ubuntu "daily build" version automatically become a fully functional stable version when it's officialy released?

Tags: upgrade, updates, daily-build

The next Ubuntu stable version will be available within less than 2 months. But I want to install the "daily build" of this next version today. If I just keep doing the basic `apt update & apt upgrade`, will I have the stable version when the next Ubuntu version is officially released? Or should I format and perform a clean install of the stable version once it's released? Will there be a practical difference between just keep updating and performing a clean install of the officially released stable version?

PS: at the momment, I'm considering to install Ubuntu 2020.04 LTS daily build and update it until the stable version is released.

Comment: Yes it will.  I bump to the development release a week after the official release (ie. I bumped to 20.04 during Oct 2019, will likely move to 20.10 come end April 2020). Be aware questions about *development* or *ubuntu+1* releases are off-topic here until release time https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, so you won't be able to ask questions here (IRC has a #ubuntu+1 area, as does Ubuntu Forums) so consider that.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

If you are already runing the pre-release version of Ubuntu, your system's normal routine `apt update` and `apt upgrade` will automatically land you in the same 20.04 LTS as though you had installed afresh.

**Warning**: Running pre-release Ubuntu means that you are volunteering to test Ubuntu. You should have (or be willing to learn) the skills to troubleshoot, to report bugs, to participate in the appropriate dev venues to discuss the issues you discover, and to do it all in a timely manner so bugs can be fixed before release,

Comment: Do I have to run 'apt update' everyday? If I skip a few days, will the system break in the next update?

Comment: You do not need to upgrade every day to avoid breakage. You should upgrade frequently while testing so that you are not discovering and troubleshooting problems that are already fixed.